# Getting error in integrating Paypal ios sdk with swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, paypal, swift5

I am trying to integrate paypal sdk in swift 5. I have written all the code, but still is is showing "payments to this merchant are not allowed(invalid client id)" , Where as the same client id is running fine in Android. Any help is much appreciated. 
In Appdelegate i wrote 
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIds(forEnvironments: [PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "test",

```
    PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : "test"])
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


    let item1 = PayPalItem(name: "Old jeans with holes", withQuantity: 2, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: "84.99"), withCurrency: "USD", withSku: "Hip-0037")
    let item2 = PayPalItem(name: "Free rainbow patch", withQuantity: 1, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00"), withCurrency: "USD", withSku: "Hip-00066")
    let item3 = PayPalItem(name: "Long-sleeve plaid shirt (mustache not included)", withQuantity: 1, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: "37.99"), withCurrency: "USD", withSku: "Hip-00291")
    let items = [item1, item2, item3]
    let subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPrice(forItems: items) //This is the total price of all the items
    // Optional: include payment details
    let shipping = NSDecimalNumber(string: "5.99")
    let tax = NSDecimalNumber(string: "2.50")
    let paymentDetails = PayPalPaymentDetails(subtotal: subtotal, withShipping: shipping, withTax: tax)
    let total = subtotal.adding(shipping).adding(tax) //This is the total price including shipping and tax
    let payment = PayPalPayment(amount: total, currencyCode: "USD", shortDescription: "Weavers", intent: .sale)
    payment.items = items
    payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails
    if (payment.processable) {
        let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
        present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn’t be processable, and you’d want
        // to handle that here.
        print("Payment not processalbe: (payment)")
    }
```

Comment: PayPal iOS SDK has been deprecated for so long. But anyways, it's probably in your dashboard config.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. Can you please elaborate how i can solve this problem. Dashboard config means in the paypal account?

Comment: i have installed pod ‘PayPal-iOS-SDK’ in my project

Comment: hi I guess PayPal sdk is deprecated. So you can try to implement Braintree it give PayPal support also.  https://www.appcoda.com/braintree-ios-integration/

Comment: Okay .Thank you very much

Comment: Actually i have done with the coding part regarding paypal ios sdk, that's why i am focusing on paypal.

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal iOS SDK is deprecated and should not be used for new integrations.

If you need a native SDK, [PayPal Express Checkout via the Braintree Mobile SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/) is supported.